# How to fix 'cannot be resolved to a variable' error in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a very simple sorting method that takes int array and sorts elements in ascending order, but I'm stuck with errors about variables

```java
    public int[] sort1(int[] a){
        for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++)
            for(int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++)
                int min = a[i];
                if (a[j] < min) {
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = min;
                    min = a[i];
                }
        return a;
    }
```

> i cannot be resolved to a variable
>   j cannot be resolved to a variable
>   min cannot be resolved to a variable

I don't know why these errors come up and how to fix them.

Comment: You are missing a `{` after `for(int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++)` (and `}` later)

Comment: You definitely should always use braces, even if the body of the `for` or `if` statements contain a single statement. It'll save you from errors exactly like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing curly braces:

```
public int[] sort1(int[] a){
    for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
            int min = a[i];
            if (a[j] < min) {
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = min;
                min = a[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

The inner loop has multiple statements, so you must enclose them with curly braces.

While the outer loop has only one statement, it is still advisable to enclose it with curly braces too.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Eran's answer, to the compiler this block

```
for (int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++)
    int min = a[i];
    if (a[j] < min) {
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = min;
        min = a[i];
    }
```

is really something more like this

```
for (int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) int min = a[i];
if (a[j] < min) {
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = min;
    min = a[i];
}
```

Remember, Java is not a whitespace-aware language like Python, for example.

The first line here is also illegal. You can't perform assignment in a for-loop without braces - probably because there is no way to access the variable after the assignment since it is immediately out of scope.